# Suitable word for one who looks after one's family

Tags: single-word-requests

I serve my family by giving them massages. I entertain them. I finance them. I'm the only **looker after** of my family. What is a suitable word in place of the expression in bold?

Comment: *Caretaker / carer*?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "look after"? Do you lend them money when they ask? Help with chores? Do all the duties a nursing home would do?

Comment: I serve them by pressing their body. I entertain them. I finance them.

Comment: @Abdullah1 By "pressing their body" do you actually mean "give massages" or something else entirely? It's not really idiomatic here.

Comment: @laurel pressing here means massage without oil. For example, one you press someone's shoulder or feet etc. then it feels relaxing for him. We do it without oil.

Comment: Massages don't have to use oil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by *look after*. Going by your example sentence, I suspect you mean ***provider*** or ***breadwinner***.

> ***[provider](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/provider)***
>   1 A person or thing that provides something.
>   *‘a leading provider of personal financial services’*
>
> > 1.1 A person who earns money to support their family.
> >     *‘he didn't like the thought of Dad being the sole provider for the family again’*
>
> ***[breadwinner](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/breadwinner)***
>   A person who earns money to support their family, typically the sole
>   one.
>   *‘when Roland's grant ran out, Val became the breadwinner’*

Comment: Might I recommend adding "head" and "man of the house"? Not that they're necessary as "provider" is the best answer, I think, but for completion's sake?

Comment: Great substitution words from all, breadwinner, caretaker, provider. Thumbs up! :-)

Comment: @SoraTamashii In many cultures, the head of the family is the one being looked after by the rest of the family, not the other way around. Especially if he is the "man of the house".

Comment: That's fair. I was actually giving my suggestion under an American perspective. You made a good point, and I now apologize for my response. Abdullah1, be sure to accept his answer with the green check if that solved your question for you. :)

Comment: @SoraTamashii No need to apologize; it's a pertinent point on both sides.  Especially since the question is (still) not entirely clear.

Comment: -1 Both *provider* and *breadwinner* are limited to the financial aspect.

Comment: @Kris This answer was provided before *any* aspects were listed (check the question's edit history). And apparently the other aspects are not critical, since OP accepted the answer. I suggest you reserve your downvoting to answers that are not useful (there is no shortage of those).

Comment: The OP never mentioned money. It's the editing that included "finance" in the list.

Comment: @Kris I never said they did. Please read more carefully: I said my answer is based  on their example sentence, which described an **only** [blank] in the family. If you know of any other aspect where *only* would be worth mentioning (e.g. being the only massager in the family), then you should post your own answer.

Comment: Whoa. Such things do happen, **easy**, michael. Btw, I did post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[carer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/carer)**
noun
*British*

> A family member or paid helper who regularly looks after a child or a sick, elderly, or disabled person.

However, the OP's coinage of *"***looker after***" would be perfect, if only it were a set phrase or idiom.